# How to add new button navbar view Mobile only (using bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create new menu with new button view in screen Mobile
like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMQjQ.png
and this menu hide if screen not Mobile

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-sociall pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-social">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        <div class="collapse  navbar-collapse navbar-social">
            <ul class="nav  navbar-nav navbar-social">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </nav>
```

this code retrun
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Eje.png

This my answer is there a better way. i used class hidden.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle " data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-social pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-social">
            <span class="icon-social"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <div class="collapse hidden navbar-collapse navbar-social ">
        <ul class="nav hidden navbar-nav navbar-social ">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="menu-social menu-facebook"></span>Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="menu-social menu-twitter"></span>twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="menu-social menu-linkedin"></span>Linkedin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="menu-social menu-skype"></span>Skype</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="menu-social menu-googleplus"></span>GooglePlus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="menu-social menu-youtube"></span>Youtube</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="menu-social menu-share"></span>Share</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="menu-social menu-rss"></span>Rss</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

and add code javascript

```
$(function() {
  if(($(window).width() <= 767)) {
    $(".navbar-social").removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you have done so far?  We would need to see existing code to be able to help you improve it.

Comment: So, do you want one mobile navigation button or two (like in your picture)?

Comment: @BenjaminRay Read the once again I add my code

Comment: @doru I need two button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the class `visible-xs`.

That's `visible/hidden-(screensize)`, yes, you can combine them: `hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg` would work, too.

So change this (starts on the 2nd line):

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   ...
</div>
```

To

```
<div class="navbar-header visible-xs">
    ...  
</div>
```

Comment: How I add hidden to
<div class="collapse  navbar-collapse navbar-social">
<div class="collapse  navbar-collapse hidden navbar-social"> 
not working to hide

Comment: It's a class, I put together a fiddle in a bit.

Comment: @mostafaamin, I have.